# How to remove underline from product in Shopify collection

Tags: css, shopify

I want to remove the underline on hover.

[Shopify Collection Link](https://oxemberg.com/collections/casual-shirt)

[image: collection image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step is to identify the element and then identify the styles being applied. In your example, the underline (border-bottom) appears when product card is in focus or being hovered. The relevant CSS rule is on line 8551 in your theme.scss.css file. So just remove this rule from your CSS file.

```
.product-card:hover .product-card__title,.product-card:focus-within .product-card__title {
    border-bottom-color:#3a3a3a;
}
```